# JOptionPane showInputDialog cancel button NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, joptionpane

I am trying unsuccessfully to trap the user into entering something for a filename.  I'm just using input dialog because the path and extension are predetermined, and I need to append to the filename after the user enters it.  As the title says I get NullPointerException any time the user clicks the cancel button.  Since the input dialog has no way to remove the cancel button I've resorted to this method:

```
while (filename.equals(null) || filename.equals("")) {
    filename=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Please enter the filename.");
    if (filename.equals(null)) filename="";
}
```

I wouldn't generally have the filename.equals(null) in 2 places like that, but I tried both separately and out of frustration I tried together too.  The NullPointerException still occurs on the line:

```
if (filename.equals(null)) filename="";
```

Is there any way to trap a cancel button (null) or prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  filename.equals(null) // Compare Object
```

Should be like

```
  filename == null // Compare Object references
```

Comment: @MaKR Thats allright. Its always the confusion about comparing object or their references.

Answer (score 1):

try to check for null like "filename == null" and not filename.equals(null),
because if it is null you will get NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned `filename.equals(null)`  - is in this case  incorrect.

The `.equals()` method compares the "value" inside String instances (on the heap) irrespective if the two(2) object references refer to the same String instance or not

the `"==" operator` compares the value of two object references to see whether they refer to the same String instance.